# Gnome Shell freezes up Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome

So basically, I'm trying to get Ubuntu all set up, it installs no problem and works just fine. But I have a problem when it comes to using Gnome Shell. For some reason, every time I install Gnome Shell it messes everything up, I'll install it, and it'll run fine for about 5 minutes then everything freezes and I have to force shut down the computer.

And it's not a problem of using just Gnome Shell, if I install Gnome Shell, I can't even use Unity without the system crashing.

I have to re-install ubuntu all over again just so everything will work (I've re-installed 3 times now)

So, right now I don't have Gnome Shell installed, but I was just kind of wondering why it does this and if there is something that I can do to fix it? If not, that's okay, Unity is cool.. but I'd prefer to run Gnome.

I'm on a Mac, dualbooting with OSX.

Comment: Nasty.. What Mac model & graphics card do you have? And where are you installing gnome shell from?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1046568):

`snippit`

Apple Intel Mac (Mactel) FAQ

Welcome to the Apple Users Forum at ubuntuforums.org.
This forum is focused on providing community support on the installation and setup of Ubuntu running on Apple hardware.

This FAQ is targeted at Users with a Intel-based Macintosh computers (mactel) with Core and Core 2 CPUs or Xeon. If you have a PowerPC-based Mac (G3, G4, G5) Please see the PowerPC FAQ. Please be sure to always check this FAQ and the Mactel-Support Community Support Documentation before asking a question in the forum, and when asking a question in the forum, post your Mac's version string.

- Can I run Ubuntu on my Mac?
  YES! You will have to reduce the size of your OSX partition in order to make room for Ubuntu.

  `Read more from the link above. It is very detailed and descriptive.`